# Drivers for Dell PERC H755 Card in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04

I am unable to install Ubuntu 18.04 OS in our Dell Server which is having Dell PERC H755 Card.

For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (ubuntu-18.04.5-live-server-amd64.iso) OS installation Error as below:
On the Guided Storage Configuration: "Block Probing did not discover any disks big enough to Support guided storage configuration."

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso) OS Installation is successful.

During my search in the internet, I have come across support page for the 18.04 hardware. However I understood that the Page might have created few years ago hence the latest release of the PERC 755H card might is not listed in the Website.

Link to OS Support [page](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201910-27388).

So request you to please assist me in installing the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server Edition in the Dell Server?

Comment: Why 18.04? Please use 20.04 or 21.04. As you stated: 20.04 does work, 21.04 will then also work. "Block Probing did not discover any disks big enough to Support guided storage configuration." we can't fix that as it is an issue with the installer itself. You could try to file a bug report but using 2[0/1].04 is a far easier option.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like bionic doesn't support this and doesn't have the necessary drivers. Experiencing the same problem with a r750xa and PERC H755N. With focal it works. However you can use the bionic hwe kernel version, which should have the drivers needed, with the GA kernel it didn't work, but HWE did the job.